# css - @media does not work with firefox and IE

Tags: css, media-queries

I Have this simple media query to check resolution of browser and accordingly display or hide the image... But it works only on Chrome and does not work on firefox and IE. any idea whats wrong with my code? or any suggestions what can I do?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1030px) {

#img{
display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1031px)
{

#img{
display:block;
}
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="img"><img src="images/bg.png" height="575px" style="position:absolute; margin-left:6px;" style="z-index:100;"/></div>
```

Comment: Do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> ?

Comment: Yes.. I have used that as well

Comment: Have you tried changing `screen` to `all` (at least for testing)?

Comment: I tried that now..
but that also duznt seem to work!

Comment: Post your HTML, your code is working for me fine (just in case: CTRL + SHIFT + M)

Comment: @JustinasJurciukonis Html Added!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your html I will assume that you are attempting to hide an image with and id of `image`? If so I would do the following.

Change the id of `img` to be a class, for example we will use `.image-class` this will mean the style can be re-used on other images on the page as IDs have to be unique.

So your html should look similar to this:

```
<img class="image-class" src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="kitten" />
```

And then for your CSS:

```
/* Mobile first strategy (no media query required) - images will not display when under 1030px)*/
.image-class {
  display: none;
}

/* Images will display above 1030px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
  .image-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C3kv/)

Comment: Works well in fiddle...
but even if I copy the same code in my file.. it does not work !!!!!

Comment: Are you able to post your HTML and full css? There must be something breaking the CSS or an unclosed tag higher up the file.

Comment: I just saw that you posted your HTML. Please see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2C3kv/

The only thing I changed was the id of `img` to a class.

Answer (score 0):

try `display:inline-block;`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1030px) {

#img{
display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1031px)
{

#img{
display:inline-block;
}
```